# How to place all node_modules in separate bundle?

Tags: webpack

How to just have everything that is loaded from node_modules in the separate bundle? What plugin or standard config should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CommonsChunkPlugin`, there is an example showing exactly this in their docs, (second example on this section):

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#passing-the-minchunks-property-a-function

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor",
  minChunks: function (module) {
    // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
    return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
  }
})
```